# I want to create a scrollable popup list window, but I'm not sure where to start. What do I use for this?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I want to have a list pop up, similar to this ancient artifact:

[image: popup]

It's just a simple list I need to fill with some data.  No multiple choice, nothing fancy.. just list of things you can tap on.  I'm new to Android development and I'm having a very difficult time trying to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are searching for dialog fragment class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

With this class you can put a layout into a popup.

He extends from dialog.

Here is the doc:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I've did this before, you need to make a custom dialog, and in the custom dialog use a custom listview.
check this out
http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/09/custom-listview-alertdialog-with-filter.html
and this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsov4v_UiGg

Answer (score 0):

The code below creates a single choice dialog populated with the item you define in a String list.

```
List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
listItems.add("Earth");
listItems.add("Mars");
// add all planets...
//Create an alert dialog with a radiobutton for every planet
final CharSequence[] planets= listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);
final AlertDialog levelDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Select a planet!");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(planets, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    switch(item)
    {
    case 0:
        // planet 1 selected, do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // planet 2 selected
        break;
    // rest of the cases....
    }
dialog.dismiss();    
}
});
levelDialog = builder.create();
levelDialog.show();
```